# Why aren't answers ordered by byte count for code golf challenges?

Tags: discussion, answers

If the shortest code wins, at least when there is the [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) tag, why is the list ordered using votes and not code size?

Comment: Unfortunately, SE doesn't support this.  We've requested it, and we may get it with the new design, but for now, we're stuck with the default sorting methods.

Comment: See [this proposal](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/9417/20260).

Comment: [Also related.](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/1987/8478)

Comment: Best solution for now: sort by active

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because we are a challenge site trapped in the body of a Q&A site. This site is based off of the same standards that [stackoverflow](http://stackoverflow.com) is based on. On a site like SO, where users ask questions to get answers, it makes sense to order answers by votes. That way, the answers that the community deems most helpful are displayed first and [rise to the top.](https://stackoverflow.blog/2011/06/optimizing-for-pearls-not-sand/).

On a challenge site like ours, this doesn't make sense. Unfortunately, there is not any good fix right now, although we have [asked for this feature](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/8358/31716).

In the meantime, I recommend sorting answers by "active", that way you can see the answers that people are still working on and improving, and get a good picture of answers as they come in.

Comment: Thank you. I agree to follow "active" tag on question code-golf

Comment: @RosLuP I like that idea too. FWIW, it [was not originally *my* idea](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/10127/how-can-we-help-users-who-are-put-off-by-the-use-of-golfing-languages#comment32362_10132)

Answer (score 18):

Sorting by code size has its own issues. Mainly, that we usually try to encourage people to golf in their choice of language, and not necessarily in golfing languages.

Sorting this way would give an even bigger advantage to golfing languages than they already have, since higher placed entries usually get more views and votes. It's hard to reconcile the top answers to ["How can we help users who are put off by the use of golfing languages?"](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/10127/14215) with a sorting method designed to explicitly feature golfing languages.